# 400 Bad Request for PUT calls Asp Net Web Api 2.2

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying to update my resource from Angular app, making Web Api call using PUT method. For some reason, all I receive is 400 Bad Request error, even when I try to do the same using Postman.

Therefore I have two questions, first - if the following code is correct, taking into account web.config file, and console output, and second - should I configure my IIS somehow to allow PUT calls ? Everything is running on IIS, and so far I've met with blogpost while working on this problem, which mention something like this - I don't really know what should be changed. cause it seems to me that I've removed WebDAV in my web.config.

web.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
                <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
            </modules>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
                <remove name="WebDAV" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath=".\AuctorAPI.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"   />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

update method in my angular service:

```js
      updateClient(client: any) {

        console.log(client); 
        var obj = JSON.parse(client);



        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');

        var body = {
          name: obj['name'],
          surname: obj['surname'],
          phone: obj['phone'],
          email: obj['email'],
          gymEntriesLeft: obj['gymEntriesLeft'], 
          martialArtsEntriesLeft: obj['martialArtsEntriesLeft'] 
        }

        console.log("ID");
        console.log(obj['id']);
        console.log("BODY");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
        return this.http.put<Client>(this.url + obj['id'], JSON.stringify(body), { headers }).pipe(
          catchError(this.errorHandler)
        );
      }
```

Angular component (calling delete method)

```js
    onFormSubmit()  {

        this.clientService.updateClient( this.clientById).subscribe(() => { 
          this.getClients();
          this.edit = false;
          this.editRowId = null;
        })

      }
```

Controller method:

```cs
    // PUT: api/Clients/5
            [HttpPut("{id}")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> PutClient(int id, Client client)
            {
                if (id != client.Id)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                _context.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;

                try
                {
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!ClientExists(id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                return NoContent();
            }
```

Comment: What if you apply `[FromRoute]` to `id` and `[FromBody]` to `client` parameters in your action? Or alternatively apply `[ApiController]` attribute to the controller?

Comment: Nothing helps, neither FromRoute/FromBody nor ApiController

Comment: What if you try to create POST endpoint? And what if you run the service as a console app, not an IIS?

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov but how? You mean to replace put with post, and leave rest as it is now?

Comment: Yes, or create another action in the controller. It's simply to see if the problem is with PUT method configuration in the IIS or something with the app or a client.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov Still the same, even though I use post method in this app for different purposes - to create customer card and sign it into db, then there is no problem. Here for some reason, IIS must block something.

Comment: Well, based on the request you send and the check you have it seems that you hit the action, but the `client` object does not have an `id`. I don't see how you set it in angular app. Have you tried to debug it and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you simply have to pass the client id to the request body as that's what's being checked in the action:

```
var body = {
  id: obj['id'],
  name: obj['name'],
  surname: obj['surname'],
  phone: obj['phone'],
  email: obj['email'],
  gymEntriesLeft: obj['gymEntriesLeft'], 
  martialArtsEntriesLeft: obj['martialArtsEntriesLeft'] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Solution has been found! 
The problem was that in body there was no ID passed to the PUT action. I debugged it in Visual Studio, by sending Postman request, and as it clearly is written in a code - bad request is returned only when passed ID differs from object's  ID. Thank you @AndriiLitvinov, I just discovered that when you posted the comment, but your solution was a favour!*